# Changing a <p> text depending from a changing value using jquery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want to make a different text appearing everytime the value I get from my `<input>` changes.

```
$(function($) {

            $(".knob").knob({
                change : function (value) {
                    console.log("change : " + value);
                },
                release : function (value) {
                    console.log(this.$.attr('value'));
                    console.log("release : " + value);
                    var x = value;
                    if( 1 <= x <= 20){
                        document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 1 to 20";}
                    if ( 21 <= x <= 41){
                        document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 21 to 41";}
                    if ( 41 <= x <= 61){
                        document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 41 to 61";}
                    if ( 61 <= x <= 81){
                        document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 61 to 81";}
                    if ( 81 <= x <= 100){
                        document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 81 to 100";}
                },
                cancel : function () {
                    console.log("cancel : ", this);
                },
                format : function (value) {
                    return value + '%';
                },})}
```

In my index.html I obviously have `<p id="PARAGRAPH"></p>` which is supposed to change everytime my value changes. 
The problem is that the only thing appearing is the string `"From 81 to 100"`, even if my value is 35.

Comment: Value is a number which can be from 0 to 100.

Comment: How value is assigned to `value`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` to check if value is inside a given interval

```
left <= val && val <= right
```

Otherwise you will always get true, because what you have now is equivalent to

```
(left <= val) <= right;
//boolean converted to a number is always <= right
```

for example `1 <= 2; //true` and `true <= 10; //true`

This seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/q2E9s/

```
$('.knob').knob({
    release: function(val) {
        var mark = $.grep([0, 20, 40, 60, 80], function(mark){
            return mark + 1 <= val && val <= mark + 20;
        })[0]; //find left mark
        $('#PARAGRAPH').html('From ' + (mark + 1) + ' to ' + (mark + 20) );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use keyup instead of change and test if the input is an integer (or a float). You also need to use `&&` .Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/6r95X/

```
$('#myIn').on( "keyup", function(){
    x = $('#myIn').val();
    // test if x is an integer
    if (x == parseInt(x)){
        if (1 <= x && x <= 20) {
            $("#res").html("From 1 to 20");
        } else if (21 <= x && x <= 41) {
            $("#res").html("From 21 to 41");
        } else if (41 <= x && x <= 61) {
            $("#res").html("From 41 to 61");
        } else if (61 <= x && x <= 81) {
            $("#res").html("From 61 to 81");
        } else if (81 <= x && x <= 100) {
            $("#res").html("From 81 to 100");
        }else{
            $("#res").html("More than 100");
        }
    }else{
        $("#res").html("Error: not an integer");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
$(function($) {

        $(".knob").knob({
            change : function (value) {
                console.log("change : " + value);
            },
            release : function (value) {
                console.log(this.$.attr('value'));
                console.log("release : " + value);
                var x = value;
                if( 1 <= x <= 20){
                    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 1 to 20";}
                else if ( 21 <= x <= 41){
                    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 21 to 41";}
                else if ( 41 <= x <= 61){
                    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 41 to 61";}
                else if ( 61 <= x <= 81){
                    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 61 to 81";}
                else if ( 81 <= x <= 100){
                    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 81 to 100";}
            },
            cancel : function () {
                console.log("cancel : ", this);
            },
            format : function (value) {
                return value + '%';
            },})}
```

Comment: Already tried, if I do that the text appearing is always "From 1 to 20". I want my text changing every-time my input value changes.

Comment: @David Thomas : See the code properly, here multiple time if condition is used, Instead of that i used nested if else

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is true multiple times, so the last one remains! Also, your conditions are logically wrong.

**Use `&&` for multiple comparisons!**

Change it to this **else if** block:

```
if (x >= 1 && x <= 20) {
    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 1 to 20";
} else if (x >= 21 && x <= 40) {
    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 21 to 41";
} else if (x >= 41 && x <= 60) {
    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 41 to 61";
} else if (x >= 61 && x <= 80) {
    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 61 to 81";
} else if (x >= 81 && x <= 100) {
    document.getElementById("PARAGRAPH").innerHTML = "From 81 to 100";
}
```

**Else-if** will stop if one condition is true. Using your method, all conditions are true for value `1`. And "From 81 to 100" is the last one, so you will see this. All the other strings get inserted, too - but in a fraction of a second, so you just don't recognize it.­

Comment: No the problem actually comes from the way he did comparisons.

Comment: Glad it helped, please consider upvoting & accpeting helpful answers.